# Alexa - saying the break text in the dialogue

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

Trying to add a break time of 20 seconds to my Alexa workout APP

I have the following output speech

"Welcome to the cardio workout. You must perform. Twenty jumping jacks in twenty seconds. Ready. Three. Two. One. Go.  We’re done. Let’s do it again. Don’t be lazy"

```
function handleCardioRequest(intent, session, callback) {
        callback(session.attributes,
            buildSpeechletResponseWithoutCard("Welcome to the cardio workout. You must perform. Twenty jumping jacks in twenty seconds. Ready. Three. Two. One. <break time='20s'/> We’re done. Let’s do it again. Don’t be lazy.", "", "true"));
    }
```

in my output speech functions, I have the following

function buildSpeechletResponse(title, output, repromptText, shouldEndSession) {

```
    return {
        outputSpeech: {
            type: "PlainText",
            text: output,
            "type": "SSML",
            "ssml": "<speak>" + output + "</speak>"
        },
        card: {
            type: "Simple",
            title: "SessionSpeechlet - " + title,
            content: "SessionSpeechlet - " + output
        },
        reprompt: {
            outputSpeech: {
                type: "PlainText",
                text: repromptText
            }
        },
        shouldEndSession: shouldEndSession
    };
}

function buildSpeechletResponseWithoutCard(output, repromptText, shouldEndSession) {
    return {
        outputSpeech: {
            type: "PlainText",
            text: output
        },
        reprompt: {
            outputSpeech: {
                type: "PlainText",
                text: repromptText
            }
        },
        shouldEndSession: shouldEndSession
    };
}
```

This works when the user requests the cardio workout but instead of a break of 20 seconds it will say break time 20seconds.

update

```
function buildSpeechletResponseWithoutCard(output, repromptText, shouldEndSession) {
    return {
        outputSpeech: {
            "type": "SSML",
            "ssml": "<speak>" + output + "</speak>"
        },
        reprompt: {
            outputSpeech: {
                type: "PlainText",
                text: repromptText
            }
        },
        shouldEndSession: shouldEndSession
    };
}
```

Comment: I think your outputSpeech object needs EITHER 'type: "PlainText",
            text: output' OR type:"SSML", ssml: output, but not BOTH. In your case, you obviously need ssml for the break mark up to be understood correctly.

Comment: Updated the code using "SSML" t now get there was a problem with the requested skill -

Answer (score 0):

You should place quotation marks around any properties that are not variables to be safe. That would be a good idea for you to do to all of your response functions. 
Because that is probably what is causing your error, since it is likely considering `shouldEndSession: shouldEndSession` as both variables, therefore returning that line as `true: true`.
You want that line to return as `shouldEndSession: true`

Try this:

```
function buildSpeechletResponseWithoutCard(output, repromptText, shouldEndSession) {
    return {
        "outputSpeech": {
            "type": "SSML",
            "ssml": "<speak>" + output + "</speak>"
        },
        "reprompt": {
            "outputSpeech": {
                "type": "SSML",
                "ssml": "<speak>" + repromptText + "</speak>"
            }
        },
        "shouldEndSession": shouldEndSession
    };
}
```

Here is a reference for the [Alexa Response Format](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#response-format). It provides a well documented break down of what properties are what types and which are required or not.

As commented above, the `outputSpeech` object takes one `type` of either `PlainText` or `SSML`. Same goes for the `reprompt` object's `outputSpeech`.
I've set them both here as `SSML` because you have the freedom to write your response messages using `SSML` tags inside the message or not.
However, if you never plan to use `SSML` tags then you can change the function to always output as `"type": "PlainText"`.

---

If you are still getting an error, please provide the function that is being sent to `handleCardioRequest` as the `callback`.